# Eager-loading only some of the properties

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models: `Question` and `Answer`. A question *has-many* answers. To eager-load a question's answers, one must write it like this:

```php
$question->load('answers');
```

However, all of the answers' properties are loaded this way. The following code, while illustrating what I want to achieve, does not work:

```php
$quesiton->load('answers')->select('id', 'body')
```

So, how can I eager-load questions' answers with only their respective `id`, and `body` properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```php
$question->load(['answers' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'body', 'question_id');
}]);
```

As you see it might be not enough to load only `id` and `body`. Assuming you have for your `Answer` model `question_id` field, you should also specify it in `select` otherwise answers won't be assigned to questions.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia You're welcome. This `get` part was my obvious mistake :)

Answer (score 4):

Using colon to specify columns is valid too:

```php
$question->load('answers:id,body');
```